# How do you iterate two variables in DataFrame, one of which is autoincrementing year?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, iteration

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
            [['New York', 1995, 160000],
             ['Philadelphia', 1995, 115000],
             ['Boston', 1995, 145000],
             ['New York', 1996, 167500],
             ['Philadelphia', 1996, 125000],
             ['Boston', 1996, 148000],
             ['New York', 1997, 180000],
             ['Philadelphia', 1997, 135000],
             ['Boston', 1997, 185000],
             ['New York', 1998, 200000],
             ['Philadelphia', 1998, 145000],
             ['Boston', 1998, 215000]],
            index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12],
            columns = ['city', 'year', 'average_price'])


def percent_change(d):
    y1995 = float(d['average_price'][d['year']==1995])
    y1996 = float(d['average_price'][d['year']==1996])
    ratio = str(round(((y1996 / y1995)-1)*100,2)) + '%'
    return ratio


city = df[df['city']=='New York']
percent_change(city)

my_final = {}

for c in df['city'].unique():
    city = df[df['city'] == c]
    my_final[c] = percent_change(city)

print(my_final)
```

My goal is to get the percentage change between each year for each city. This way I can chart the percentage changes on a line chart. I can only figure out (crudely as it may be) how to do it for one year. Even them, I don't think I'm properly assigning the year to the result in that one. I don't know how to iterate it through ALL the years. I'm so confused, but if someone can help me out, I feel like I can truly start to learn.

So, from 1995 to 1996 the percentage change in price is as follows:

```
{'New York': '4.69%', 'Philadelphia': '8.7%', 'Boston': '2.07%'}
```

Going through examples were easy, but the data was so abstract to me. Now that I have actual information that I want, I don't know how to process it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?pandas.DataFrame.pivot) and [rolling windows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html?pandas-dataframe-rolling) to achieve the desired output:

```py
relative_changes = (
    df
    .pivot('year', 'city', 'average_price')
    .rolling(window=2)
    .apply(lambda price: price.iloc[1]/price.iloc[0] - 1)
    .dropna()
)
```

I prefer not to hardcode the formatting inside the data so that we can use them in further calculations. Any formatting can be applied later when needed. For example, when displaying data on the screen:

```py
display(
    relative_changes
    .style
    .format("{:.2%}")
    .set_caption("Relative changes")
)
```

[image: figure]

The same with charts:

```py
ax = relative_changes.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10,6))
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelrotation=0)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda y, pos: f'{y:.0%}')
ax.yaxis.grid(linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8)
ax.set_title("Relative changes of the average price")
```

[image: figure]